# Rewrite Urls with question mark and ampersand

Tags: .htaccess, variables, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

On my website I have categories with urls like so

`www.example.com/?foo` and `www.example.com/?bar`

In these categories I have articles with urls like this:

`www.example.com/?foo&nr=12`

and groups with urls like this:

`www.example.com/?foo&group=somegroup`

I am trying to rewrite

`/foo` to `/?foo`, `/bar` to `?bar` etc.; `/bar/12` to `/?bar&nr=12` etc. and `/foo/somegroup` to `/foo&group=somegroup`

It should work both with and without final slash.

The (admittedly clueless) things I tried either did nothing or resulted in a server error. At some points I also tried just getting the `&nr=xx` bit or simply the categories. Some of them are:

- `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)([^&]+) RewriteRule /?(.*) %1/$1
  [QSA]`
- `RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /?$1&nr=$2`
- `RewriteRule ^/([^/]+) ?nr=$1 [L]`

Comment: What's the name of the file handling the queries? `index.php`? And are `foo` and `bar` "fixed" words or just examples for even more possible variables?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, assuming the file handling the queries is `index.php` and `foo` and `bar` don't change to something else, you could start like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^foo$ foo/ [NC,R]
RewriteRule ^foo/$ index.php?foo [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^foo/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ foo/$1/ [NC,R]
RewriteRule ^foo/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?foo&group=$1 [NC,L]
```

Now you should be able to do the `bar` part on your own!

Btw. if you really want your query string to only be `?foo` (without a value, like so: `?foo=somevalue`) you'll have to check for `foo`'s existence differently than you would for e.g. the `somegroup` part.

Comment: Kay, sorry for not getting back – I didn't expect anyone to answer any more so I did not check back in a while. Thanks so much for your input, I am trying it out at the moment!

Comment: I see! Well, let me (and anyone else who might come across this thread) know how it worked out for you!

Comment: Thanks Kay. First, to answer your question: "foo" and "bar" are indeed variables and can be anything. 
Secondly, I tried your code and it does indeed show `?foo&nr=23` when I type `foo/23`, so I'm definitely making progress.
However, no css styles are working any more even though from a previous attempt I have 
`# Don't match real existing files so CSS, scripts, images aren't rewritten
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`
in place.

Comment: Maybe you could help me understand the steps I am trying to achieve: Do I need two rules in place, one redircting all requests with "?" and "nr=" to the clean urls and another which then shows the content of the "dirty" url when the clean one is typed in?

Comment: I might be a bit slow at the moment, but I always come back to report success and/or failure eventually – nothing more annoying than finding a question with the only comment being "ah never mind, fixed it myself", isn't it? Cheers!

Comment: Hey Seul, hmm, looks like the redirect works, which answers the question you originally asked. (: The CSS might be related, but is a separate issue. I've never used the Rewrite Condition you quoted here, so have never run into any issues with my CSS (the link in your php file stays the same, after all) - have you already tried it without that RewriteCond and made sure the file, as linked in your php, exists on the server?

Comment: Kay, apparently your comment from Nov 20th asking me to accept your answer was deleted. To answer your question: I accept answers once they help me solving the original problem, which was not the case here.

Comment: Hm, I didn't delete my comment myself, weird. Could you maybe explain how the answer didn't solve the problem you described in your original question?